# WildFly 10 rpmbuild

Tags: wildfly-10, rpmbuild

I am building a custom RPM for WildFly 10. I am stuck on deploying the systemd service. The spec file is able to deploy the code as well as create a user, however, no matter what avenue I try, I cannot get the RPM to create the service. I have tried `install -m 644` but rpmbuild has tries finding the file, even if I specify full path:

e.g. `install -m 644 %{buildroot}/opt/%{name}/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd/%{name}.service %{buildroot}/usr/lib/systemd/system/%{name}.service`

I have also tried a series of systemd scriptlets as noted in https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets, but that does nothing (the RPM will build with exit 0 status, but the service is never created). Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
$ cat SPECS/wildfly.spec
Name:           wildfly
Version:        10.0.0.Final
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        WildFly (JBoss) Application Server
Group:          System Environment/Daemons
License:        LGPL 2.1
URL:            http://wildfly.org
Source0:        http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/%{version}/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

ExclusiveArch:  x86_64 i686
ExclusiveOS:    Linux

%{?systemd_requires}
Requires:       systemd
Requires:       shadow-utils
Requires:       java >= 1.8.0
Requires:       /etc/init.d/functions
Provides:       %{name}

%description
WildFly Application Server packaged from the binary distribution.

%prep
%setup -q -n %{name}-%{version}

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/%{name}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/var/log/%{name}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/var/run/%{name}
cp -R . %{buildroot}/opt/%{name}

%pre
getent group %{name} >/dev/null || groupadd -r %{name}
getent passwd %{name} >/dev/null || \
    useradd -r -g %{name} -d /opt/%{name} -s /sbin/nologin %{name}

%post
alternatives --install /etc/alternatives/%{name} %{name} /opt/%{name} 100
%systemd_post %{name}.service

%postun
alternatives --remove %{name} /opt/%{name}
%systemd_postun %{name}.service
userdel %{name}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,0755)

%dir /opt/%{name}
/opt/%{name}/appclient
/opt/%{name}/bin
/opt/%{name}/docs
/opt/%{name}/domain
/opt/%{name}/jboss-modules.jar
/opt/%{name}/modules
%attr(-,%{name},%{name}) /opt/%{name}/standalone
/opt/%{name}/welcome-content
%dir /var/log/%{name}
%dir /var/run/%{name}

%doc /opt/%{name}/copyright.txt
%doc /opt/%{name}/LICENSE.txt
%doc /opt/%{name}/README.txt
```

Comment: Did you include the system service files in the files section? You can do rpm -qlp <package file> to check whether it is included.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks.